# get public key from wallet.dat

Tags: blockchain, wallet.dat, public-key

Is there a way to get the public key of a given wallet.dat to check the balance in the blockchain to avoid having to install the wallet and read all blocks?

Comment: PyWallet can be useful for this.

Comment: You're going to need programming knowledge to do this task either way. I don't believe there is a simple tool out there to accomplish this...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a `wallet.dat` file does not contain a single public key; it contains multiple keypairs. You can use PyWallet as Meni says, but if it's too technical for you, you can install the wallet but don't have to download all the blocks. Your public keys will show up under "Receive coins" (even if the blockchain is not downloaded), and you can copy each of them into [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) to check the balance of each address. Adding them all up will give you your total balance.